# XMPP connection hanging on "Resource Binding" process using xmedianet library

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, xmpp

As a complete beginner in the field of instant messaging (using XMPP protocol), as well as windows phone 8.1 app development; I am trying to start off by using [xmedianet library](https://xmedianet.codeplex.com/) in order to connect to a server and communicate using XMPP protocol. After implementing the following [example](http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/using-xmpp-and-openfire-server-windows-phone-8) and tweaking it to my needs. 
Here's the part of the code where I configure the connection parameters:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using WP8Xmpp.Resources;
using System.Net.XMPP;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace WP8Xmpp
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    private Boolean IsXmppSuccess { get; set; }

     /// <summary>
    /// Xmpp Client
    /// </summary>
    public XMPPClient ObjXmppClient { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// XMPP Connection 
    /// </summary>
    public XMPPConnection ObjXmppCon { get; set; }    

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsXmppValid();
    }

    private void IsXmppValid()
    {
        ObjXmppClient = new XMPPClient();
        //initializing the xmpp client with credentials
        ObjXmppClient.JID = "user@domain.com";
        ObjXmppClient.JID.Resource = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
        ObjXmppClient.Password = "acc_password";
        ObjXmppClient.Server = "server_uri";*/
        ObjXmppClient.AutoReconnect = true;
        ObjXmppClient.Port = 81; // I've already tried 5222 but 81 is the correct port in this server's case.
        ObjXmppClient.RetrieveRoster = true; 
        ObjXmppClient.PresenceStatus = new PresenceStatus() { PresenceType = PresenceType.available, IsOnline = true };
        ObjXmppClient.AutoAcceptPresenceSubscribe = true;
        ObjXmppClient.AttemptReconnectOnBadPing = true;
        ObjXmppCon = new XMPPConnection(ObjXmppClient);
        ObjXmppCon.Connect();
        ObjXmppClient.Connect();

        //initializing the xmpp connection

        ObjXmppCon.OnAsyncConnectFinished += ObjXmppCon_OnAsyncConnectFinished;


        ObjXmppClient.OnStateChanged += new EventHandler(xMPPClient_OnStateChanged);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

    } ...
```

When I launch this application using the WP 8.1 emulator and attempt a connection. Everything works fine until the Resource Binding step. I get the following output on the VS2013 console:

```
<--stream:features><ver xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:rosterver"/><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>
Setting state to CanBind
Setting state to Binding
<--<
<--iq id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0f08b82b9f1f" to="user@domain/Resource" xmlns="jabber:client" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>user@domain/Resource</jid></bind></iq>
```

Followed by nothingness except for a few "thread exit" messages and the program terminating after a few minutes.

I've been at it for days now.. I've tried all possible scenarios for the connection parameters, even tried fiddling with the library's code to no avail. Could anyone try to replicate this configuration with the same library to see if it's a problem on my side?

Note: connection to the server with the same account using another xmpp client works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the problem was that, for some reason, the "Bound" state was not firing even though the binding attempt returned a successful result. I've managed to "fix" this the ugly way by using Thread.sleep() and then changing the state manually to "bound" (note that the same trick is used to get to the "session" state). Here's a sample of my "patchwork" code:

```
 void xMPPClient_OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (ObjXmppClient.XMPPState)
        {
            case XMPPState.Binding:
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        ObjXmppClient.XMPPState = System.Net.XMPP.XMPPState.Bound;
                    }    
                );
                break;
            case XMPPState.Sessioning:
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    ObjXmppClient.XMPPState = System.Net.XMPP.XMPPState.Session;
                }
                );
                break; ...
```